# what does this bash snippet do?

Tags: bash

I am not very bash-fluent, but I really need to comprehend what does the following mean and what is the explanation?

The code is not mine, but I trust the source
I am especially bothered by the expression in the `if` clause, what's the benefit of having `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` twice?

```
  if [[ -z "${ENABLE_CREDS}" && "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS}" && "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    ENABLE_CREDS=1
  elif [[ -z "${ENABLE_CREDS}" && "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS}" -eq 1 ]]; then
    ENABLE_CREDS=0
  fi
  export ENABLE_CREDS
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `if`-statement performs a test that involves testing the shell variable `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` twice.  The first time the variable is used, it tests whether the variable's values is non-empty.  If it is, it tests whether the non-empty value is numerically equal to zero.

Another way to write the code is as follows

```bash
if [[ -z "${ENABLE_CREDS}" && -n "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS}" && "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    ENABLE_CREDS=1
elif [[ -z "${ENABLE_CREDS}" && "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS}" -eq 1 ]]; then
    ENABLE_CREDS=0
fi
export ENABLE_CREDS
```

Note the inserted `-n` test operator, which tests for a non-empty string.  This operator is implicit when you test on just a string.

It is unclear whether this initial test on `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` being non-empty is needed (we don't see the rest of the code). It could be needed if the variable has a chance of being empty, in which case the test with zero would be *true* (and it's possible that the programmer didn't want this to trigger setting `ENABLE_CREDS` to `1`).

This means that

- for `ENABLE_CREDS` to be set to `1`, `ENABLE_CREDS` needs to be either unset or an empty string, `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` must be non-empty and numerically equal to zero,
- for `ENABLE_CREDS` to be set to `0`, `ENABLE_CREDS` must be unset or empty, and `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` must be numerically equal to 1.

---

Without knowing more of the context of this code, I might venture to guess that the purpose of the `if` statement as a whole is to set `ENABLE_CREDS` to either `0` or `1` if it's not already set to some value, depending on the logical inverse of the variable `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS`.

```bash
if [ -z "$ENABLE_CREDS" ]; then
    if [ "${DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS:-0}" = 1 ]; then
        ENABLE_CREDS=0
    else
        ENABLE_CREDS=1
   fi
fi
```

If `ENABLE_CREDS` is empty, this tests `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` (or the string `0`, if the variable is unset or empty) against `1`, and sets `ENABLE_CREDS` to `0` or `1` depending on the outcome of that test.

The difference here is that this code always leaves `ENABLE_CRED` with *some* value.  It will either have its old non-empty value, or it is guaranteed to have the value `0` or `1`.

This is in contrast to the code in the question, which may leave the value of the variable empty if `DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` is empty or if it's some value like `2` (or indeed if it is the name of some other variable whose value is not 0 or 1; arithmetic evaluation is tricky, which is partly why I opted for a string comparison in the code above).

Comment: And if `$DISABLE_CUSTOM_CREDS` happens to be empty, `ENABLE_CREDS` would not get to either value, which might be a surprise somewhere. (Not that I could know what the code is supposed to do, but with the `-z "${ENABLE_CREDS}"` tests it sure looks like it might try to set the value if it's not already set.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes. It's unfortunately difficult to guess the intention when not more code is given, but it is quite possible that the current code is not *quite* doing what's expected in all cases.